# mysql find count of records in a different table by date

Tags: mysql, join, timestamp

I worked late into the night and a good portion of today trying to write this query, but alas, no luck. Hoping someone here might see what I'm missing!

I'm trying to add results from another table to a query I already have working. Here's the working query:

```
`SELECT B.Usr_Sb_Grp, DATE(CONVERT_TZ(A.TimeStamp,'UTC','America/Chicago')) AS Day, B.ID, B.Qstn, 
SUM(IF(A.AnswerID = '0', 1, 0)) AS 'NULL', 
SUM(IF(A.AnswerID = '1', 1, 0)) AS 'Poor', 
SUM(IF(A.AnswerID = '2', 1, 0)) AS 'Good', 
SUM(IF(A.AnswerID = '3', 1, 0)) AS 'Great' 
FROM User_Responses AS A 
LEFT JOIN Question AS B ON A.QID = B.ID 
LEFT JOIN Cat_X_Ques AS C ON B.ID = C.QuesID 
LEFT JOIN Question_Categories AS D ON C.CatID = D.ID 
WHERE B.Usr_Sb_Grp='2' AND D.QType='7'AND MONTH(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(A.TimeStamp,'UTC','America/Chicago'))) = MONTH(NOW()) 
GROUP BY TO_DAYS(Day), B.ID`
```

It outputs columns of:

```
Usr_Sb_Grp | Day | ID | Qstn | NULL | Poor | Good | Great
```

And the results are accurate.

Now, I have another table that I want to add results from, specifically from the dates and ID in the current results. Meaning, I want to extend the count fields of (Poor, Good, Great) and add more count columns from the results of the other table from the same date.

This is where I'm currently at with the query to no avail:

```
`SELECT B.Usr_Sb_Grp, DATE(CONVERT_TZ(A.TimeStamp,'UTC','America/Chicago')) AS Day, 
B.ID, B.Qstn, 
SUM(IF(A.AnswerID = '0', 1, 0)) AS 'NULL', 
SUM(IF(A.AnswerID = '1', 1, 0)) AS 'Poor', 
SUM(IF(A.AnswerID = '2', 1, 0)) AS 'Good', 
SUM(IF(A.AnswerID = '3', 1, 0)) AS 'Great', 
SUM(if(USB.AID='0', 1, 0)) AS 'NULL', 
SUM(if(USB.AID='21',1,0)) AS 'Service', 
SUM(if(USB.AID='22',1,0)) AS 'Menu Selection', 
SUM(if(USB.AID='23',1,0)) AS 'Taste', 
SUM(if(USB.AID='24',1,0)) AS 'Food Temperature' 
FROM User_Responses AS A 
LEFT JOIN Question AS B ON A.QID = B.ID 
LEFT JOIN Cat_X_Ques AS C ON B.ID = C.QuesID 
LEFT JOIN Question_Categories AS D ON C.CatID = D.ID 
LEFT JOIN User_Sub_Responses AS USB ON A.TimeStamp = DATE(USB.TimeStamp) LEFT JOIN Question_Child_Questions AS CQ ON USB.AID = CQ.ID 
LEFT JOIN Question_Sub_Questions AS SQ ON CQ.Parent_ID = SQ.ID 
WHERE B.Usr_Sb_Grp='2' AND D.QType='7'AND MONTH(DATE(CONVERT_TZ(A.TimeStamp,'UTC','America/Chicago'))) = MONTH(NOW()) 
GROUP BY TO_DAYS(Day), B.ID`
```

This outputs the correct format:

```
Usr_Sb_Grp | Day | ID | Qstn | NULL | Poor | Good | Great | NULL | Service | Menu Selection | Taste | Food Temperature
```

...but the results for the added columns are all 0, even though checking the User_Sub_Responses table, there are definitely results for this month tied to the appropriate QID.

I've tried many different variations of the query above with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: it would only mean that USB.AID is null. USB is a left join so it it may or may not have a value. try doing a select on USB.AID ONLY to confirm this theory.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to successfully query User_Sub_Responses and get data back for the dates and QIDs. In the query above when I join USB.QID with A.QID, I get values in the new columns but all of the data is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this

```
A.TimeStamp = DATE(USB.TimeStamp)
```

should be

```
A.TimeStamp = USB.TimeStamp
```

When applying the DATE() function time will be removed from the timestamp field and the table link will not resolve. If there was another reason for applying this function, e.g. your data types differ, you might want to fix that first to ensure integrity.